# How to compare the columns of a datatable based on the column name and value?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable, datarow, datacolumn

I have a datatable like below one which is not fixed it can contain n number of columns. I need to compare the column values based on the column name and update the other row value

E.g

dtFinYearValues

```
    dtColumnName | 2017AU | 2017CN | 2018AU | 2018CN | 2019CN | 2020CN
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
     Value       | -1234  | -500   | -300   | 1000   | 1000   | -500
     LatestValue | -1234  | -500   | -300   | 500    | 1000   | -500
```

LatestValue of 2018CN --> Sum of 2017CN Value (-500) and 2018CN Value(1000).

For the above datatable i need to compare the column name and update the value accordingly
Conditions :

1) If the value is -ve update the LatestValue with Same Value.

2) If the value is +ve check whether any -ve value exists for previous fin-year of same country like (In the above datatable 2018CN Value is +ve but 2017CN value is negative so the sum of 2017CN and 2018CN has to be updated for 2018CN-->Latest Value.)

I can't hard-code the column number as there can be different country fin year combination, i need to compare the value of one country with the same country only.
How can i code this in vb.net?

Comment: "i need to compare the column name". Um, compare it to what?

Comment: The Value of 2018CN is 1000, for 2018CN to update the value of latestValue i need to check whether 2017CN exists . If exists i need to check whether that value is -ve if it is -ve i need to sum values of 2017CN and 2018CN and update the value to latestValue of 2018CN which is done in above datatable.

Comment: Examples are all well and good but we need to know what the actual rules are if you want us to suggest how to implement those rules in code. Are you saying, without actually saying, that, for each column, you need to break the name into a four-digit number and a two-letter string and then check whether a column exists with the same string and a number that is 1 less? If that is what you need to do then that is what you should have said you need to do. If you need something else then please describe it in similar detail. Examples come AFTER the rules, not before. Hence the term "as an example".

Answer (score 1):

Can you bring back the data from the db another way? If so look at using SQL unpivot (the unpivot could also be done in your code using your original dataset but you would have to manually code this). This will give  you 3 columns (name, value, latestvalue). This will be easier to process. Updates can still be done using your original dataset.

Comment: Agreed. The columns should be [Year], [Country], [Value], [LatestValue]